# Prove a set open from a topological space whose elements are nxn matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrix-rank

I'm working independently through Wallace's "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology" and I'm unsure of a claim in one of the exercises.  The question states

> **II.2.2**.  Let $M_n$ denote the set of square $n$-rowed matrices with real elements.  If the elements are taken as coordinates in $n^2$-dimensional Euclidean space $M_n$ becomes a topological space.  Prove that the set of matrices of rank greater than or equal to $r$ for any $r\le n$ is an open set in this space.

My understanding of the question is that the Euclidean space on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ gives $M_n$ a topology in the sense that a set $U_A$ of $A\in M_n$ is a neighborhood of $A$ if there is a bijective $f:M_n\to \mathbb R^{n^2}$ such that the image $f(U_A)$ is a neighborhood of $f(A)$.

I have no problems with $M_n$ being a topological space because if $A,B\in M_n$ we can define $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|_F$ with $\|\cdot\|_F$ as the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) and it's clear then that if $\forall\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R^{n^2}$,$d(\alpha,\beta)$ is the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), then $d(A,B)=d(f(A),f(B))$.  I suspect that he threw in the reference to $n^2$-Euclidean space to bypass the **Frobenius norm**.

Anyway, I've come up with the following counterexample to the claim that the set of matrices of rank greater to or equal to $r$ for any $r\le n$ is an open set in the space:

> We can define  $f:M_4\to\mathbb R^{16}$ with $$f(A)=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10},a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{15},a_{16})$$ if $A\in M_4$ with $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\a_5&a_6&a_7&a_8\\a_9&a_{10}&a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{13}&a_{14}&a_{15}&a_{16}\end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Let $\epsilon \gt 0$, $a\in\mathbb R$, and $b\lt a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  Then, define $A,B\in M_4$ by 
>   $$A=
> \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0\\
> a&b&a&b\\
> b&a&b&a\end{bmatrix}
> \text{ and } 
> B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0\\
> a&b&a&b\\
> a&b&a&b\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Then, \begin{align}d(f(A),f(B))&=\sqrt{4(b-a)^2}\\&=2(b-a)\\&\lt2(a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}-a)\\&=\epsilon\end{align}
>   So, rank $A=2$ and rank $B=1$.  Define $O=\{ M\in M_4: \text{rank } M\ge 2\}$.  Clearly, $A\in O$, but $B\notin O$.  However, $f(B)$ is in every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f(A)$.  So, $B$ must be in every neighborhood of $A$, so $O$ is not a neighborhood of $M_4$.  Since $O$ is not a neighborhood of $M_4$, it cannot contain any neighborhoods of $A$, so $O$ cannot be open.

I was unable to locate any errata for this book, so there may have been a typo, but it's more likely that my understanding of the question is incorrect.  So, assuming that the exercise's assertion is correct, where is the flaw in my counterexample?

Comment: It looks to me like $b$ depends on $\epsilon$ and thus your matrices $A$ and $B$ depend on $\epsilon$. For analogy, here's a similar proof that $(0,1)$ is not open, let $x = \epsilon/2$ and $y = 0$, then $x \in (0,1)$, but $|x - y| < \epsilon$ and $0\not\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I also doubt the veracity of the statement.  On the contrary, let's say, $r = n$.  Then the matrices of rank $r$ are exactly the invertible ones; i.e., the set of these matrices is the pre-image of the open set ${\bf R} \setminus \{0\}$ under the continuous map $A \mapsto \det(A)$.  Hence, the invertible matrices form an *open* set.

However, for $r < n$, a **strict** inequality, the matrices of rank $r$ are the preimage, under $\det$, of the closed set $\{0\}$,

Comment: @avs No, the statement is fine. Remember its the set of matrices of rank $\ge r$ that is to be proved open, and that set has a lot of invertible matrices in it.

Comment: So, the set $O$ is the pre-image of the open set $\mathbb R$ under $A \mapsto \det(A)$.  What this tells me is that you can union any set of singular matrices to the set of invertible matrices and still call it an open set.  Is that correct?

Comment: @zhw., thanks, I have misread the statement.

So, in the special case $r = n$, the matrices with rank $\geq r$ (and, consequently, $ = n$) are the invertible ones, hence constitute an open set.

Can we look at the mapping that sends a matrix $A$ to its Jordan canonical form with the eigenvalues in (say) decreasing order down the diagonal?

Comment: You can get the rank from the determinants of the minors, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra) under "Alternative Definitions". Thus, if you define $D_k: M_n \to \mathbb R^{n_k}$ to be the map that sends a matrix $A$ to the determinants of all its $k$-minors (say there are $n_k$ of them (note, $n_n = 1$ and $D_n = \det$)). Then, you can see that rank $A \ge r$ if and only if $D_r(A) \neq 0$. From this, you can conclude the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But your $A,B$ are really moving targets, because $b$ depends on $\epsilon$ and hence so do the corresponding matrices. Really, they should be denoted $A_\epsilon, B_\epsilon.$ So you've shown $d(f(A_\epsilon), f(B_\epsilon)) < \epsilon,$ but that's no contradiction.